# How to add text different color on JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Can anybody help me with simple log, I have to add at first line on JTextPane log messages with chosen color ( green ok, red failure ). How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 37):

This will print out "BLAH BLEG" in two different colors.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

        Style style = textPane.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);

        try { doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "BLAH ",style); }
        catch (BadLocationException e){}

        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.blue);

        try { doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "BLEH",style); }
        catch (BadLocationException e){}

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Look here: [Style Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#textpane)

and check the section labeled: *An Example of Using a Text Pane* for a great example of how to dynamically change the colors.

Answer (score 10):

for [JTextPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) you can implements [StyledDocument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#textpane) some examples for that on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextPane.htm

Comment: +1 for being the first poster to link to the Swing tutorial which contains a working example that uses Styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML for that and then do

```
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
```