# How do I change color of every word in JTextPane?

Tags: java, jtextpane

Every time key is typed i get jpane's characters, split them using spaces and color every word in other (random) color. This fragment of code does the work:

```
private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
            String[] codeWords = codePane.getText().split("\\s");
            StyledDocument doc = codePane.getStyledDocument();
            SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            int lastIndex = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < codeWords.length; a++) {
                Random random = new Random();
                StyleConstants.setForeground(set, new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(lastIndex, codeWords[a].length(), set, true);
                lastIndex += codeWords[a].length();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it changes EVERY char of jpane's text, not every WORD. How to solve it?

Comment: Give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068398/how-to-add-text-different-color-on-jtextpane

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML inside JTextPane. read about it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the space between words:

```
//lastIndex += codeWords[a].length();
lastIndex += codeWords[a].length() +1;
```

of course this assumes there is only a single space.