# Use JTextPane to style code

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextpane

How can I use JTextPane to style a section of text as "CODE," like you often see on forums, or you see here on stack overflow?

```
public static main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * Look at this Code Block, ain't it grand?
     * I wish I had something like this in my program.
     */
}
```

Or how I have seen done on wikipedia, where the text is like this:
http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/4516/example.JPG

Thank you!

**FINAL UPDATE**
Vishal K's answer was exactly what I needed. Not a duplicate, as was suggested.

**UPDATE**

Thank for you the responses. The difference between what I am looking for and what was suggested as a possible answer above is that I am interested in not only changing the font, but also adding a background (a border around said background would be a plus, but not required. I do not need to do syntax highlighting.
I think HTML tags may be the way to go, and if so, that is really the question: How can I use html to format the code in such a way? I will play with the example provided in the answers and let you know.

 P.s. I already read the links to the oracle tutorials before asking this question.

Comment: You can set the font. However, if you want to change colors of keywords, identifiers etc, then it's going to be hard. You'll have to write a complete library to find words and change their color.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#textpane

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add text different color on JTextPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068398/how-to-add-text-different-color-on-jtextpane)

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextPane.htm

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate, this questions is a superset of the one you linked. The OP here first needs a method to determine highlight color for the text (variables, reserved words, class types, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use JTextPane to style a section of text as "CODE," like you
>   often see on forums, or you see here on stack overflow?

Using HTML Tags. But before this you would have to set contentType to be  ("text/html").
Here is a simple Example for this :
[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class TextPaneDemo {
  static void addIt(JTabbedPane tabbedPane, String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextPane ta = new JTextPane();
    ta.setContentType("text/html");
    ta.setText("<HTML><BODY><CODE> import java.io.*; <br> public class MyIO{}</CODE><br></BODY></HTML>");
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(ta);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(jsp);
    tabbedPane.addTab(text, panel);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JTabbedPane Sample");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = f.getContentPane();
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    addIt(tabbedPane, "Tab One");
    content.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do Everything that you want to using HTML Tags within the JTabbedPane. If you are quite well versed in HTML rendering then it wont't be a big problem for you to achieve what you want using HTML tags.

Comment: I notice that you didn't close the <CODE> tag. Is there a reason?