# Recoloring word while typed

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextarea

I want to code a program, and I would recolor specific words.

Like this:

Hey there I like carrots with bones.

I want to let carrots automatically while it is typed, make it blue. 
Wow do I do that in code?

I already tried this:

```
public void getWord(String whatword){
   if(jtextarea.contains(whatword){
      //Stuck on here
     }
```

For example:
If I type this:

I like carrots and tuna.

I want to change the color from carrots and tuna to blue.
And the other words need to stay black.

Now I don't know how to recolor the word, and if this if statement even works. 
So, how do I fix this?

Sorry, I am dutch, so you need to do it with this language, I think

Comment: As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727548/java-change-the-document-in-documentlistener/14727657#14727657)

Answer (score 3):

A `JTextArea` is only meant to contain plain text and cannot color certain words. If you want to be able to color different words, you need to use a [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) or a [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).

For more information, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400946/how-to-change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-a-jtextpane). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068398/how-to-add-text-different-color-on-jtextpane) may also be helpful

Here is an example:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

Style style = textPane.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);
String word = "Hello";

if (word.equals("Hello") {
    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), word, style);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.blue);

    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), word, style);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This makes a String `word`. If word is `"Hello"` it will be displayed in red, otherwise it will be displayed in blue.

Comment: Oke, so if i use a JTextPane, how can i do that then?

Comment: I have added an example now, and looking at the linked questions can show you how to use `JTextPanes` too

Comment: *"how can i do that then?"*  The answer to that is more than could fit in an SO answer. That's why we have [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).. +1 for this answer.